# How to crawl various websites to find specific department using Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a list of university urls like `www.harvard.edu, www.berkeley.edu`etc.
I need to find the cse department urls in the respective websites What i initially set out to do was to crawl through links in url given and by specifying depth , say 3 it will follow links and try to find cse or computer or lists of words in the links scraped on that page  matching links along with their anchor text are returned as results into a csv file.
if no links containing cse or as such words it should return not found or something like that
idea is to push the csv file later onto a database. How can I do this?

Comment: what have you got so far then? any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite complex task and I recommend using database using structure like this:

```sql
TABLE pages (
    `absolute_url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `visited` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
    -- Additional fields
    UNIQUE KEY (`absolute_url`)
)
```

Little explanation:

- `absolute_url` contains full URL to page (starting with `http[s]://`) and has unique index placed on it. This way you make sure you won't end up in recursion or process multiple link twice
- `visited` informs you on whether site was already visited (and processed). This field is important for preventing double visitation again and allow you to recover gracefully if your program crashes (ie. network downtime)

You may implement those things on your own via CSV, or associate arrays, but database is most familiar solution for me.

And the algorithm would go as:

```
database.insert( 'http://www.harvard.edu')
database.insert( 'http://www.berkeley.edu')

# In case of failure you'll start at this point:
while database.get_count( WHERE visited = 0) < 0:

    for url in database.get_records( WHERE visited = 0):
        content = http_client.load(url)
        time.sleep(5) # You don't want to flood server

        # Problematic URLs will be parsed later
        if (not content) or (http_client.is_error):
            continue; 

        for i in content.get_all_urls():
            i = make_absolute(i, url)

            # Also don't crawl remote sites, images, ...
            if not is_valid_url(i):
                continue
            database.insert(i)
```

*This is pseudocode, I won't implement it all for you.*

Answer (score 0):

For solve your problem you can use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) framework.

Extracted from scrapy web:

> Scrapy is a fast high-level screen scraping and web crawling framework, used to crawl websites and extract structured data from their pages. It can be used for a wide range of purposes, from data mining to monitoring and automated testing.